# Remote-control block does not assign variables

Tags: grails, spock, functional-testing, remote-control

I'm writing functional tests with Spock and Geb in Grails 2.5.6 using the remote-control plugin.

I have something like this in a `when` block:

```
String someString
remote {
    someString = SomeDomain.findByName("Some Name").someValue
}
```

In the `then` block that follows, `someString` is `null`. Trying to debug the issue, a breakpoint in the `remote` block is not hit.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the way `remote-control` executes the given closure, the assignment to the local variable is not performed.

Do this instead:

```
String someString = remote {
    return SomeDomain.findByName("Some Name").someValue
}
```

Keep in mind that serialization is performed there, so this will not work for every type.